# remove document on real time with DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
if(documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
    MessageAndUserInfo info = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(MessageAndUserInfo.class);
    messageList.add(info);
    info.setId(documentChange.getDocument().getId());
    info.setThreadId(threadId);
    db.collection("users").document(documentChange.getDocument().getString("senderId")).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            info.setUsername(task.getResult().getString("firstName"));
            if(completeCount++ == value.size() -1){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

}else(documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED){
    ThreadAndUserInfo info = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(ThreadAndUserInfo.class);
    threadsList.remove(info);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I'm developing a Message app. I send the document changes to an Adapter, that happened on real time for everyone. That's fine, but when I want to remove a Message I want to do it on real time. I mean everyone can see the document deleted, I did it on the Adapter but the change takes effect only for the user who delete the message. I'm thinking on return the item position from the adapter and returning it on Fragment but Idk how.

I can see changes on the RecyclerView when I call adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position), but I require the position of the Item...

when I add a Item to recycler view I can see the changes on the fragment with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() without refresh it. and I want to implement the same "effect" when I remove a message.

Comment: When the `DocumentChange.Type.REMOVE` fires you'll need to remove the document that was removed from your `messageList` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter. Did you do that?

Comment: "but there is not a real time change" I'm not sure what you mean there. If you set a breakpoint on that `threadsList.remove(info);`, run in the debugger, and remove a document: does it then reach that breakpoint? If so, does your code successfully remove the item from the `threadsList`?

Comment: When I mean "real time change" is showing the change on this case document removed from firebase in the Recycler View, The item is removed from the list with: threadList.remove(info), but I still can see the document on the Recycler View until I refresh the fragment the Item is removed, basically I don't want to refresh the fragment for see any changes. I'm using snapshotListener event and works fine when I add a item to the Recycler View I can see the change without refresh the framgent

Comment: Hmm... if your adapter renders the items in `threadsList`, then the code looks good to me. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: I also don't spot the problem, but if you understand Kotlin, most likely this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) will help. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/SwipeToDelete).